# Why boost uniform_int_distribution takes a closed range (instead of a half-open range, following common C++ usage)?

Tags: c++, boost

The title says it all. There's even a [warning](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_random/tutorial.html) in the documentation pages:

> Warning: Contrary to common C++ usage `uniform_int_distribution` does not take a half-open range. Instead it takes a closed range. Given the parameters 1 and 6, `uniform_int_distribution` can can produce any of the values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6.

Why do this, when the common practice in C++ is to use open ranges [begin, end) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only with closed ranges, you can create a `uniform_int_distribution`, that produces any integer:

```
uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(std::numeric_limits<int>::min(), std::numeric_limits<int>::max());
```

If this would be a half-open range, you could never reach `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`, but only `std::numeric_limits<int>::max() - 1`.

It's the same situation for `std::uniform_int_distribution` in the C++11 standard library.

Half-open ranges for iterators are common, because one can easily express empty ranges (by setting `begin == end`). This doesn't make sense for distributions.

---

Reference: Stephan T. Lavavej mentions this exact reason in his talk ["rand() Considered Harmful"](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) at Going Native 2013 (around minute 14). This talk is about C++11 `<random>`, but of course the same reasoning applies to boost as well.

Comment: @MarkRansom Well what else do you see?

Comment: If I knew that I'd add my own answer. Your point about half-open ranges is good too. I just wanted to leave open the possibility that someone could produce the documented rationale from the boost mailing lists.

Comment: @MarkRansom Fair enough :)

Comment: It's been more than a year now, but I still should ask: what about uniform_real_distribution? Why it's exclusive if it prevents user from generating DBL_MAX?

Comment: @tonytony I think that's a good and valid follow up question. I don't know why, to be honest. Please, go ahead and pose a follow up question by opening a new question and referencing this one :-)

Comment: I think "doesn't make sense" is a bit far-fetched, what if you want random array index?

Comment: A random array index can be achieved with any uniform int distribution, even if the range contains just one number. It's different for uniform real distributions, but those shouldn't be used for array indices for the obvious reason of not being integral. For real distributions with the half-open range, there is no number in the interval [x,y), so it doesn't make any sense to pick numbers in that range